# Collect data from multiple spreadsheets into one spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, collections

I have 184 audit sheets in one folder. I want to reference one cell in each of these sheets and bring them back in to one master spreadsheet.

I have a code that does the opposite that sends a value to each sheet in the folder and changes it to the value that I want. So in essence I want to do the opposite of the script below:

```
function getdata() {


 var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1gbA2JI1DYNku7SQPaCq1Qk27hnbimPag").getFiles()
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());

  var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Jan");
  var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A3');
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();

var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('Front Sheet'); 
var destrange = destsheet.getRange('B5'); 
destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);         
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example code doesn't appear to match your explanation but I think I got the basic idea so I made up some of the needed details on my own. I included filenames, ids and 'A3' values.  You can choose to modify as needed.

```
function getdata(month) {
  var monthA=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  var date=new Date();
  var mss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ms=mss.getSheetByName("Master Sheet");
  var vObj={name:[],id:[],value:[]};
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1gbA2JI1DYNku7SQPaCq1Qk27hnbimPag").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fid=file.getId();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fid);
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(monthA[date.getMonth()]);
    var rg = sh.getRange('A3');
    vObj.name.push(file.getName());
    vObj.id.push(fid);
    vObj.value.push(rg.getValue());
    vObj['month']=monthA[date.getMonth()];
  }
  vObj.id.splice(0,0,'ids');
  ms.appendRow(vObj.id);
  vObj.name.splice(0,0,vObj.month);
  ms.appendRow(vObj.name); 
  vObj.value.splice(0,0,'values');
  ms.appendRow(vObj.value)
}
```